# Does the Platform Session Cache interpret multiple Site Guest User sessions separately?

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, session, platform-cache

I'm considering using a Platform Session Cache for User sessions on my force.com site. My question is:

Does the Platform Session Cache interpret the "Force.com Site Guest User" as a single session, even if multiple computers/browsers are actually using the Force.com site?

Comment: I would assume it would consider it a single session based on my experience with force.com Sites because the Guest Site user is quirky in several ways. You can't access it in Hierarchy Custom Settings, any package licences assigned to don't appear in the Assigned Licences view etc. So I'm not optimistic that it would work well with Cache either...but happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Seems to be working in sandbox... but I agree with you, the Guest Site user can get weird and its behavior in production can be different. I'm hesitant to make this change without more confidence because if I'm wrong, no one that uses the web app will be able to log in.

Comment: I know Cookies seem to work ok - so if you need some client side cache, that might be an option?

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering going that route, I would just prefer to have it server side so I don't have to worry about my coworkers disabling cookies and losing access to the site.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is curious, the guest site user is unfortunately not allowed to use the Platform Session cache.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/97272)

Comment: I am the author, and yes, it does answer it. Force.com Site Guest users do not have access to the platform session cache at all, therefore the question about whether or not the platform cache considers the user a single session or not is kind of moot. Am I speaking to a bot..?